# need to plot my own shape file using raster package in R for spatial data analysis?

Tags: r

I use the following code to plot my data:

```
library(dismo)
#download occurence data from gbif
taxus_occurence <- gbif("taxus", "wallichiana*", geo=FALSE)
View(taxus_occurence)

head(taxus_occurence)
dim(taxus_occurence)
#select the records that have longitude and latitude data
colnames(taxus_occurence)
tx_coordinates <- subset(taxus_occurence, !is.na(lon) & !is.na(lat))
dim(tx_coordinates)

# extract columns containing lat, long and country names
# select variables v1, v2, v3
myvars <- c("lat", "lon", "country")
newdata <- taxus_occurence[myvars]
newdata

#make a map of the occurrence localities
library(maptools)
## Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
data(wrld_simpl)
raster-taxus <- plot(wrld_simpl, xlim=c(-100,100), ylim=c(-100,100), 
axes=TRUE, col="light green")
# restore the box around the map
box()

# add the points
points(tx_coordinates$lon, tx_coordinates$lat, col='orange', pch=20, 
cex=0.75)
# plot points again to add a border, for better visibility
points(tx_coordinates$lon, tx_coordinates$lat, col='red', cex=0.75)
```

I get the fine result.

Now instead of using the whole world map, I have my own shape file on my laptop for my area of interest. How can I import the shape file using the same package?

Comment: There are lots of resources online for this. Check out `sf` package

Comment: if it's an ESRI shapefile (`.shp`), try `shapefile()` from the `raster` package